# Get events when an Azure Durable Function changes status

Tags: azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-durable-functions

I want to monitor a running instance of an Azure Durable Orchestrator Function for changes (like when it completes, fails etc)

I know that I can poll the status API for changes, but i was wondering if there were any push-based functionality. I've looked into the source code but I can't seem to find any clues to extension points, interfaces etc that enables this.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think so, have not seen it documented or used anywhere. Table Storage sadly is not supported as a function trigger so don't see a way without continiously pooling the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, publishing orchestration lifecycle events (such as created, completed, and failed) is limited to a custom [Azure Event Grid Topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-grid/overview). This feature is currently in preview. Refer [Durable Functions publishing to Azure Event Grid (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-event-publishing).

#### Durable Functions 2.x

Add a `notifications` section to the `durableTask` property of the file, replacing `<topic_name>` with the name you chose. If the `durableTask` or `extensions` properties don't exist, create them like this example:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "notifications": {
        "eventGrid": {
          "topicEndpoint": "https://<topic_name>.westus2-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events",
          "keySettingName": "EventGridKey"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Event Schema

The following list explains the lifecycle events schema:

- **`id`**: Unique identifier for the Event Grid event.
- **`subject`**: Path to the event subject. `durable/orchestrator/{orchestrationRuntimeStatus}`. `{orchestrationRuntimeStatus}` will be `Running`, `Completed`, `Failed`, and `Terminated`.
- **`data`**: Durable Functions Specific Parameters.

  - **`hubName`**: [TaskHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs) name.
  - **`functionName`**: Orchestrator function name.
  - **`instanceId`**: Durable Functions instanceId.
  - **`reason`**: Additional data associated with the tracking event. For more information, see [Diagnostics in Durable Functions (Azure Functions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics)
  - **`runtimeStatus`**: Orchestration Runtime Status. Running, Completed, Failed, Canceled.
- **`eventType`**: "orchestratorEvent"
- **`eventTime`**: Event time (UTC).
- **`dataVersion`**: Version of the lifecycle event schema.
- **`metadataVersion`**:  Version of the metadata.
- **`topic`**: Event grid topic resource.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm testing it out now and it looks promising.